# Pen pressure in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, hardware, wacom

Is there any way to detect pen pressure in actionscript?

Comment: Vote on the bug here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1762

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not in flash itself. you will need to write a daemon, that processes the information and binds a local port for flash to communicate to. flash will then connect to the daemon, allowing it to send input data to flash. solutions like these have already been implemented for numerous input controllers, such as joysticks and the wiimote.

Answer (score 3):

If your SWF is embedded in a web page, then you are able to access the pen pressure via the JavaScript if the wacom browser plugin is installed (usually installs with drivers). You could then forward it onto Flash.

See [Wacom Software Dev support - Web browser plugin demos](http://www.wacomeng.com/web/index.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if covers your situation, but there's an [actionscript library for wacom bamboo minis](http://mini-developer.wacom.eu/SDK.mvc).

[image: flash on bamboo dock]

[image: air logo transparent]